# adapting the size of a function iteratively in matlab/ convert string to function

Tags: matlab, handle

I want to convert a string which is in a `cell` (`size 2*len(x) × 4`) into a function handle `f=@(x) F`.

The first line of `F` is

```
'x(1)'   'cos(2*pi*'  'F(1)'  '*1/Fe)'
```

The following lines are similar but the input of `x` is counting up. `Fe` and `F` are actually variables.
The size of the matrix F depends on the length of the vector x. It should be `2*len(x) x 1`

Is this possible?

What I actually wanted to do is to write a function which size changes dependent on the size of the vector `x`. The only way I saw to adapt the size was to introduce the string.

Comment: ..OK, I'm lost :) Can you perhaps give an example of 2 different values of `x`, and the corresponding expected output of your cell/function handle?

Comment: Thanks; :) Finally I cheated to solve my problem, by writing a function in a different m-file, so no hurry. But it would be quite usefull to know.

Comment: OK, but I don't get your question :) Could you provide example input/expeced output?

Comment: The input is the string F. The output I want to have is a function handle `f = @ (x) F`, where he recognizes the concatenated string F as a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still quite fuzzy on the details (or why you want to do what you want to do), but I guess this (or something similar) would do the trick:

```
f = str2func(['@(x)' F{:}]);
```